# SQL - Display all empty rows with Count() Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, database

These are my tables:

```
Categories table
================
id (fk)
category_name


Items table
===========
id (pk)
item_name
category_id (pk)
```

One **category** has many **Items**

One **item** have one **category**

Let's say I have these data:

```
Categories
==========
id       category_name
-----------------------
1        Foods
2        Beverages
3        Computer
4        Cats


Items
=====
id    item_name   category_id(fk)
1     Rice        1
2     Chicken     1
3     Mouse       3
4     Keyboard    3
```

Query that I used to count items grouped by category name:

```
SELECT
    categories.id,
    categories.category_name,
    COUNT(items.item_name) AS items
FROM
    items
INNER JOIN categories ON items.category_id = categories.id
GROUP BY
    category_name
```

I've tried the above query to display the counting, but it doesn't show all rows from Categories table. Well, of course some item might not be in a category, but how do I show the empty Category as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

could you try this?

```
SELECT
    categories.id,
    categories.category_name,
    COUNT(items.item_name) AS items
FROM
    categories LEFT JOIN items
        ON items.category_id = categories.id
GROUP BY
    categories.id, category_name
```

**to print out ONLY empty categories**

```
SELECT
    categories.id,
    categories.category_name
FROM
    categories LEFT JOIN items
        ON items.category_id = categories.id
WHERE items.category_id IS NULL;
```